# How do I get Windows Terminal to stop asking me every time I paste something into the terminal?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-terminal

Everytime I paste something into Windows Terminal I get the following annoying message that's attempting to save me from myself.  
I don't need it!  How can I make it go away?
[image: Dialog with the following message appearing in the middle of Windows Terminal after pasting which reads: Warning You are about to paste text that contains multiple lines...blah blah...]

Comment: Note that there are a whole bunch of attacks which rely on making the copied text different from what you saw on the website where you copied from. This warning can probably protect you from a large subset of them.

Comment: @Nobody: Damn, that's a really good PSA.  It would be great if the clipboard knew the source of the content, that way the warning could be disabled if text is copied directly from another terminal or from text-editor-of-choice.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From Microsoft's Windows Terminal [docs about Terminal Interaction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/interaction#warn-when-the-text-to-paste-contains-multiple-lines):

> #### Paste warnings:
>
> ##### Warn when the text to paste contains multiple lines
>
> When this is set to true, trying to paste text with multiple lines will display a dialog asking you whether to continue or not with the paste. When it's set to false, the dialog is not shown and instead the text is pasted right away. In most shells, one line corresponds to one command so if you paste text that contains the "new line" character into a shell, one or more command(s) might be executed automatically upon paste, without you having time to validate the commands. This can be useful if you often copy and paste commands from untrusted websites.
> **Property name:** multiLinePasteWarning
> **Necessity:** Optional
> **Accepts:** true, false
> **Default value:** true

To change these settings:

Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while selecting *Settings* in the Windows Terminal dropdown menu. This will open the editor associated with `json` files, typically Visual Studio Code if installed.

*At the root* of your `settings.json` (not under any other key, just inside the *first* level of brackets), add:

```
"multiLinePasteWarning": false,
```

Make sure to add a comma before or after, depending on where you place it.

For example:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",
    "multiLinePasteWarning": true,
    "actions": 
    [
    ...
}
```