# How to disable Developer Command Prompt (cmd.exe, DOS box) warning when pasting multiple lines

Tags: windows

Windows 11 has changed the Visual Studio "Developer Command Prompt for VS 20xx" (cmd.exe, "DOS box") to behave like the terminal and warn if you attempt to paste in multiple lines of commands:

"Warning: you are about to paste text that contains multiple lines..."

This answer has instructions to stop this in terminal, is there an equivalent for the developer prompt?  - [How do I get Windows Terminal to stop asking me every time I paste something into the terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/1677982/how-do-i-get-windows-terminal-to-stop-asking-me-every-time-i-paste-something-int)

Comment: When you say "Developer Command Prompt" you mean that comes with Visual Studio?

Comment: The same JSON config line should work for the developer command prompt as well. But it can be tricky to figure out WHICH JSON file corresponds to that specific command prompt. On my own system I added the JSON command to Terminals default JSON file and that seems to have cured all terminal sessions.

Comment: You'll probably need to look at the bat file that loads the developer command prompt and see if the settings from that other question can be added somewhere.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas  - yes, "Developer Command Prompt for VS 20xx" on the start menu.  I'm pasting in some different after-build steps including code-signing that vary so they aren't in the build process itself.  (Question edited to add this)

Comment: Yes; I can confirm the existing solution works for the developer terminal. Just modify the WT profile section for that particular profile

Comment: I just verified what @Ramhound and Tonny stated (under Windows 11 VM).  You should be good to go with the knowledge they were nice enough to provide.  Terminal is prettier for sure but in ways.. needs tweaking to have the same feature set.

Comment: If you get this working using that knowledge, post yourself a detailed answer.  Wait a day.  Accept your own answer (if it is still indeed the best).  Collect points.